# How to apply onClickListener in navigationView?

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I want to add an **`onClickListener`** to navigation view header's items like I have made Login or Register buttons there and I want to add Listener to the navigationView.

So, that when I click to the navigationView, my login activity would open. And I have been using Navigation Drawer Activity for this and I have done this coding  in MainActivity.

Please tell me how to do so.

I have simply make an object of navigtionView and then apply Listener to it there is no error but it is not working

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
nav_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
nav_view.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Simply refer navigation view in your activity and add click listener to it! What have you tried? Show your efforts.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show some code? Or just add a New Activity with the Navigation Drawer template... It shows exactly how to use a click listener

Comment: You should share your code and what you've tried. refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Your best way to add click listeners to your header in the `NavigationView` is by getting the header and then setting the listeners to the required views directly, like this:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
Button loginButton = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
Button registerButton = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_register);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
registerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```